# Can multiple subscribers subscribe to same EventHub with $default consumer group

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, publish-subscribe, azure-eventhub

I have two Spark jobs which basically subscribe the same EventHub with $default consumer group. Will it going to work?

Let's assume that multiple device who ingest the data into same event hub and let's say event ingest xyz into event hub now will both spark job will get this xyz?  Second is there any chance that conflict can occur let's say first Spark job reading x partition and second Spark job is also trying to read the x partition.

```
Endpoint=sb://abc.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=allow;SharedAccessKey=abcd=;EntityPath=abc
```

```scala
val customEventhubParameters = EventHubsConf(connStr).setMaxEventsPerTrigger(maxEventTrigger)

val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load();
logger.info("Data has been fetched from event hub successfully");
val messages = incomingStream.withColumn("Offset", $"offset".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Time (readable)", $"enqueuedTime".cast(TimestampType)).withColumn("Timestamp", $"enqueuedTime".cast(LongType)).withColumn("Body", $"body".cast(StringType)).select("Offset", "Time (readable)", "Timestamp", "Body")

implicit val formats = DefaultFormats;

val ob = new EventhubMaster();
```

Comment: you can use setConsumerGroup API in the EventHubsConf class. Please note that you will need to create a consumer group if it doesn't exist.

Comment: by creating multiple consumer group resolved my issue.